# Cowboy and jiffy websocket_handle events

Tags: json, erlang, websocket, cowboy

I am using cowboy and jiffy (Json library) for my websocket.. I can receive the data from client in my websocket_handle as of now i have code similar to this

```
websocket_handle({text, Msg}, Req, Handle) ->
    Message = jiffy:decode(Msg),
    case Message of
```

pattern1 -> 
                 ...........
            pattern2 ->
                 ..........
         end,
        {ok, Res, State}

However instead of this i would like to pattern match at the handle level...

```
  websocket_handle({text, pattern1}, Req, State),
  websocket_handle({text, pattern2}, Req, State)
```

Problem is that i cant use jiffy:decode in parameter of websocket_handle.. so i cant write something like

```
 websocket_handle({text, jiffy:decode(Msg), Req, State})
```

How to make it work???

Comment: Hi Atul. Besides ending up with less lines (if it worked, as is doesn't as you found out), is there another reason why you would want to decode within the function signature? As I'm in inclined to say that using the `case` expression later on is a good way, or after a decode, call a different function that pattern match similar to the case steps.

Comment: Hey Ward thanks for the reply.. I can use case without any problem but I want to avoid that for a simple reason in future there can be many events and every event can return different response.. So I would like to separate them using function signature...And moreover I think matching function signature is a cleaner approach :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you like pattern matching in the function signature vs a case expression, you could 'forward' the decoded message to another 'internal' function.

```
websocket_handle({text, Msg}, Req, Handle) ->
    Message = jiffy:decode(Msg),
    websocket_handle_({test, Message}, Req, Handle).

websocket_handle_({text, Pattern1}, Req, Handle) ->
    {ok, Req, State}; 
websocket_handle_({text, Pattern2}, Req, Handle) ->
    {reply, OutFrame | [OutFrame], Req, State};
websocket_handle_({text, PatternN}, Req, Handle) ->
    {ok, Req, State}.
```

Comment: Hey ward, Thats a nice solution (Wonder why it didnt click me :) ). The only problem i can think about is what if few events want to send reply and few not.. so few event returns {ok, Req, State} and few {reply, OutFrame | [OutFrame], Req, State} then again I will have to do put condition in websocket_hande for response...

Comment: Thanks ward... I got that but i am kinda confuse as i am still a new to erlang... So, when cowboy calls websocket_handle and from there we have called websocket_handle_ so anything websocket_handle_ will return it will go back to websocket_handle correct? or it will directly be replied to websocket?? Because i was confused that the function will return to websocket_handle..

Comment: the value of the last statement of a function will be returned to the caller. So in this example the `websocket_handle` will return the tuple you return in `websocket_handle_`. As `websocket_handle_` is the last statement in `websocket_handle`, this will return the tuple as well.

Comment: Yaa ok got it.. it websocket_handle_ return will be returned as websocket_handle doesnt return anything to websocket..cool. .. ty

Comment: A Json object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. I don't see how one can pattern match if client might send it in unordered.... E17 has map pattern matching so that would work. But with a proplist?

Answer (score 1):

So just change to

```
websocket_handle({text, Msg}, Req, Handle) ->
    websocket_handle_({text, jiffy:decode(Msg)}, Req, Handle).

websocket_handle_({text, Pattern1}, Req, Handle) ->
    %% do stuff,
   {ok, Req, State};
websocket_handle_({text, Pattern2}, Req, Handle) ->
    %% do stuff,
     {reply, [OutFrame], Req, State};
websocket_handle_({text, PatternN}, Req, Handle) ->
    %% do stuff,
     {reply, OutFrame, Req, State}.
```